# El ajax solo me funciona en la última publicación

Tags: php, ajax

La cosa es que le agrego todas las funciones que quiero a mis publicaciones pero no sé por qué sólo la primera publicación obtiene esas funciones. Por ejemplo en el `ajax` tengo la función de `preventDefault` para el formulario pero solo la primera publicación obtiene la función es como si rechazara las demás y solo se enfoca en la primera.

Miren el ejemplo de mi código, ojalá alguien se interese aunque el código sea un poquito largo, No sé si alguien se tomar el tiempo en echarle un ojo la cosa es que mi código es masivo por así decirlo es un proyecto de una red social.

Aqui me redirige al logearme, Nota: al varios archivos externos en el cual incluye el header footer sidebar y mas pero este es el cuerpo de todas las publicaciones la cual no esta en archivo externos por cuestiones de rendimiento.

```
 introd
<?php
/******************  INISCIAR SESSION PARA EL USUARIO **************************/
    session_start();
    include"externos.php";

    if (!isset($_SESSION["usuario"])) {

        header("location:index.php");
        }

?>

    <?php  headerb();?>
    <?php  screen(); ?>
    <?php  saludo(); ?>

   <?php  footer(); ?>



  <!-- START OF PUBLICAR-->
<div id="btn_p" style="width:450px">
  <center>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 135px;">
             <div id="bom">

             <a href="#"  id="mostrar"> <img src="img/public2.png">Publicar</a>
          </div>
        </td>
           <td style="width: 130px;">
             <div id="bom">

             <a href="#"  id="boxi" class="calificar2"> <img src="img/public2.png">Viewmarket</a>
          </div>
        </td>
          <td style="width:130px;">
             <div id="bom">

             <a href="leer.php"  id="mostrar"> <img src="img/public2.png">Contactar</a>
          </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
       </table> 
       </center>
  </div> 
  <!-- END OF PUBLICAR-->


  <!-- MARKET PLACE-->
 <div id="market">

   <h5>Bienvenido a Viewbox</h5>

   <p>Pon tu  publicacion en la bolsa de valores!</p>    

   <button id="elije" class="btn btn-outline-dark active" style="display: inline-block;">Elige tu publicacion</button> 
   <button class="btn btn-outline-info">Info</button>

<div id="modal_content">
<!-- Modal -->

<div class="modalok">

  <div class="modal-in">
    <div id="cerrar_content""><h4 style="color: #009D91; font-weight: bold; ">Elije tu publicacion</h4>
    <a href="#" id="cerrar">Salir</a>
    </div>
    <hr>
      <?php

include"conexion.php";

$copy = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM contenido WHERE id_user= '{$_SESSION["id"]}' AND evaluaciones > 0 ORDER BY fecha DESC");

  while ($copias = mysqli_fetch_assoc($copy)) { 

  $rangos = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT SUM(valor) AS valor3 FROM rankin WHERE  id_post='{$copias["id"]}'");
       $rangor=mysqli_fetch_array($rangos);
        if ($copias["evaluaciones"]>0) {
    ?>
  <div class="contenido_copias" style="padding: 15px;">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>

          <h6 style="margin-top: 10px; float: left;">Rango <?php echo$rangor['valor3'];?></h6>
        </td>
         <td>
         <img src="imagenes/<?php echo $_SESSION['avatar']?>" width="40px" height="40px" style="border-radius: 50%; margin-top: -45px;">
           <h6 style="font-weight: bold; margin-top: -10px;"><?php echo ucwords($copias['usuario']." ".$copias["apellido"]);?></h6>
        </td>
         <td>
           <button class="btn btn-outline-dark active" style="float: right; margin-top: -35px; background: rgba(0, 157, 145, 0.9); ">Copiar</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="copias_img" style="background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); ">
       <img src="imagenes/<?php echo $copias['imagen']?>">



   </div>
   <h6 style="float: left; color: #007D91; margin-top: 8px; " >Evaluaciones <?php echo$copias["evaluaciones"];?></h6><h6 style="float: right; color:#007D91; margin-top: 8px;">Comentarios 13</h6>
   <br>
   <hr>


</div>

<?php
 }else{

  echo"<h2>No tienes publicaciones con rango suficiente!</h2>";
  echo"<img src='img/sad.png'>";
  break;

}
}

?>

</div>
 </div>
<h3>Sigue</h3>
</div>
</div>
 <!-- MARKET PLACE END-->



  <!-- START OF PUBLICACIONES-->

  <!-- START OF FORM PUBLICACIONES-->

<div id="publicaciones" >
<div class='bg'>

<form action="insertar_publicacion.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">

<textarea id="text" name="coment" placeholder="Escribe aqui tu comentario..."></textarea>

<br>
<hr>
<img src="img/image.png" width="30px" height="30px" id="camera" >

      <input type="file" name="imagen" id="cargar_foto">
      <label for="suvir">Seleccionar foto</label>
<input type="submit"  value="Subir foto" name="public" id="suvir">


</form>



</div>

</div>

 <!-- END OF FORM PUBLICACIONES-->



<!-- AQUI LEEMOS TODAS LAS PUBLICACIONES-->
 <?php


$publication = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM contenido ORDER BY fecha DESC ");
        while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($publication)) {


?> 


<aside id="principal" class="principal" '>
   <div id="cabesera">
    <table width="100%" >
        <tr >
          <td id="cab" width="30px" >

            <img src="img/medalla3.png" style="border-radius:50%; left:10px;  margin-top:-35px; position:relative; background: white; width: 40px; height: 40px; float: left; display: block; " >
            <?php
              $likero=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT SUM(valor) AS valor1 FROM rankin WHERE  id_post='{$registro["id"]}'");
                      $rango= mysqli_fetch_array($likero);

                 $contar=mysqli_num_rows($likero);

                 ?> 
         <b><a href="#"  style=" left: -40px; position: relative; color:rgba(0, 130, 145, 0.9); font-size: 13px; ">Rango <span id="resultadoss"><?php echo $rango["valor1"];?></span></a><b>
        </td>

  <td  id="hora" width="100px" style="border-left: solid 1px #D8D8D8; border-right: solid 1px #D8D8D8;">

      <center> <img src="imagenes/<?PHP echo $registro["avatar"];?>" style="border-radius:50%; margin-top: 0px; background-color: darkgrey; border: solid 1px #848484; " id="red" width="40px" height="40px"><br>

          <a href="perfil_one.php?id=<?php echo $registro['id_user'];?>"  style="color:rgba(0, 130, 145, 0.9); font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px;  "><?php echo ucwords($registro['usuario']." ".$registro['apellido']);?></a>

          <p style="font-size:12px; color: darkgrey; margin-top: -5px; "><?php echo $registro["id"];?></p>
     </center>
  </td >

  <td width="35px" >
    <div id="despli"></div>

     <div  class="desko2"   id="<?php echo $registro['id'];?>">
          <img src="img/ojo.png" width="25px" height="25px">
      </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
<!--AQUI INSERTAMOS EL COMENTARIO DE LA PUBLICACION-->
<div id="coment_div" style="margin-top: -20px; background: rgba(250,250,250,.2);  ">


      <?php echo  $registro['comentarios'];
  ?>


</div>
<!--AQUI TERMINAMOS EL COMENTARIO DE LA PUBLICACION-->



 <!--AQUI INSERTAMOS LA IMAGEN DE LA PUBLICACION-->

  <div  style="width: auto;   background-color: #2E2E2E;" id="imagen_g">
           <!--trucos para imagenes  filter: grayscale(100%); filter:brightness(0.4); --> 
          <table width="100%">
            <tr>
              <td >
                <center>
                 <?php echo"<a href='#'><img src='imagenes/".$registro['imagen']."' style='width:auto; max-width:100%; max-height:500px; '></a>";?></center>
               </td>
            </tr> 
          </table>


  </div>
  <!--AQUI TERMINAMOS LA IMAGEN DE LA PUBLICACION-->



  <!--EMPEZAMOS LA CASILLA DE LAS EVALUACIONES--> 

<?php 

     $comprueba = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM rankin WHERE id_post = '{$registro["id"]}' AND usuario_id = '{$_SESSION["id"]}' ");
      $contar=mysqli_num_rows($comprueba);
    if( $contar== 0 ) { ?>



<div class="casilla1"  id="casilla1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Evaluar publicacion">      
<table id="tabla2" width="100%" style="margin-top: 0px;" name="btn">

      <tr>
      <td id="viewers" width="170px" >
<!--ESTE ES EL FORMULARIO PARA EVALUAR LAS PUBLICACIONES EL CUAL SOLO LA PRIMERA PUBLICACION LO TOMA LAS DEMAS NO -->
        <form name="val" action="evaluaciones.php" method="GET" id="formulario">

        <select name="cali" id="cali" class="cali" >
          <option name="uno" value="0" id="record"><p>Evaluar!</p></option>
          <option  value="1">1 de 10</option>
          <option  value="2">2 de 10</option>
          <option value="3">3 de 10</option>
          <option value="4">4 de 10</option>
          <option value="5">5 de 10</option>
          <option value="6">6 de 10</option>
          <option value="7">7 de 10</option>
          <option value="8">8 de 10</option>
          <option value="9">9 de 10</option>
          <option value="10">10 de 10</option>

        </select>
        <select name="valo" id="valo" style="display: none;">
          <option value="<?php echo$registro['id']?>"></option>
        </select>

         <button type="submit" name="eva2"  class="calificar" id="<?php echo$registro['id']?>" style=" background-color:white;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left"><img src="img/uncheck.png" width="18px" height="20px" id="change1"> </button>


         </div>

         <br>

     </form>
     <?php
     $compruebame = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM rankin WHERE id_post = '{$registro["id"]}' ");
     $cuenta=mysqli_num_rows($compruebame);

     ?>
          <a href="#mis_usuarios"  style="left: -20px; top:10px; padding: 2px; color:rgba(0, 130, 145, 0.9); font-size: 14px; position: relative;" id="<?php echo$registro['id']?>" class="miembro" name="resulta ">Evaluaciones <span id="resultados"><?php echo$cuenta;?></span> </a>
        <div id="resultame"></div>
          </td>

        </tr>
     </table>

</div>
 <?php  } else { ?>
<!--ESTO SE PRESENTA SI YA EL USUARIO EVALUO LA PUBLICACION -->
 <div class="casilla1"  id="<?php echo$registro['id']?>" title="Evaluar publicacion ">      
<table id="tabla2" width="100%" style="margin-top: 0px;" name="btn">

      <tr>
      <td id="viewers" width="170px" >

        <form name="val" action="evaluaciones.php" method="GET" id="formulario">

        <select name="cali" id="cali" class="cali" >
          <option name="uno" value="0"  >Reevaluar!</option>
          <option  value="1">1 de 10</option>
          <option  value="2">2 de 10</option>
          <option value="3">3 de 10</option>
          <option value="4">4 de 10</option>
          <option value="5">5 de 10</option>
          <option value="6">6 de 10</option>
          <option value="7">7 de 10</option>
          <option value="8">8 de 10</option>
          <option value="9">9 de 10</option>
          <option value="10">10 de 10</option>

        </select>
        <select name="valo" id="vali2" style="display: none;">
          <option value="<?php echo$registro['id']?>"></option>
        </select>

         <button type="submit" name="eva2" class="calificar" id="<?php echo$registro['id']?>" style=" background-color: #424242; border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); " ><img src='img/tick.png' width='18px' height='22px'> </button>



     </form>
     <?php
     $compruebame = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM rankin WHERE id_post = '{$registro["id"]}' ");
     $cuenta=mysqli_num_rows($compruebame);

     ?>
          <a href="#mis_usuarios" name="resulta" id="<?php echo$registro['id']?>" class="miembro" style="left: -30px; top:10px;  color:rgba(0, 130, 145, 0.9); font-size: 14px; position: relative;">Evaluaciones <span id="resultados"><?php echo$cuenta;?></span> </div >
            <div id="resultame"></a>

          </td>

        </tr>
     </table>
</div>

<?php  } ?>
 <!--TERMINAMOS LA CASILLA DE LAS EVALUACIONES-->



<!--EMPEZAMOS LA CASILLA DE LOS COMENTARIOS -->  
<div id="casilla2">
    <table>
       <tr>

         <td>
               <form  action="" method="get" id="<?php echo $registro['id']; ?>">
                 <select name="coment_f" id="cali" class="coment_f" style="width: 150px;" >
                 <option >Comenta Facil !!</option>

                 <option >Me encanta</option>
                 <option >Divertido/a</option>
                 <option>Estoy de acuerdo</option>
                 <option>Inteligente</option>
                 <option>No estoy de acuerdo</option>
                 <option>Me enoja</option>
                 <option>Aburrido/a</option>
                 <option>Increible</option>
                 <option>Eres fenomenal</option>
                <option>Me enamora</option>

                </select>

                <button type="submit" name="eva2" class="calificar" style=""><img src="img/social_ballooni.png" width="20px" height="20px"> </button>

                <div>
                <br>

                <a href="" style="margin-top: -4px; color: #007D71; font-size: 14px;">Comentarios 0</a>
                </div>
                <br>

               </form>
            </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<!--trminamos LA CASILLA DE LOS COMENTARIOS --> 
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<hr style="color: #FFFFFF;">


<div id="coments" style="background: rgba(250,250,250,.9);">


</div>


<div id="texto">

 <!-- aqui comentarios-->
<form action="re_coment.php"  method="post">


      <div class="input-group mb-2" style="width: 90%; margin: 0 auto;">
  <div class="input-group-append" >
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="button">Comentar</button>

  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Escribe un comentario..." aria-label="" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <img src="imagenes/<?php echo$_SESSION['avatar'];?>" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; border-radius: 50%; margin-bottom:-10px;">
</div>
</div>

</form>


<br>


   </div>

</aside>
<?php 


}
?>


</body>
</html>








<!-- END OF PUBLICACIONES-->
<!-- NOTA: LAS FUNCIONES ESTAN EN UN ARCHIVO ESTERNOS QUE ES EL HEAD DEL ARCHIVO HTML INCLUYENDO LOS CSS BOOTSTRAP JQUERY Y MAS-->

CODIGO AJAX PARA PREVENIR EL SUBMIT

$(document).ready(function () {
//EL PREVENTDEFAULT  SOLO ME FUNCIONA LA ULTIMA PUBLICACION ESTE ES EL ERROR CON EL CUAL NO HE PODIDO DAR   
$(".calificar").click(function(e){

   $("#formulario").submit(function(e){

           e.preventDefault();


     $.ajax({


       url:"evaluaciones.php",
       type:"GET",
       data:$("#formulario").serialize(),
       dataType: 'json',


       success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $("#resultados").html(data['valor1']);
        $("#resultadoss").html(data['valor2']);
        $("#change1").replaceWith("<img src='img/tick.png' width='18px' 
 height='22px'>");
        $("#change2").css("background-color", "#424242","border","solid 1px  #009D71;");
         $("#record").html("<h5>Reevaluar!</h5>");
    },
   error:function(data){

    console.log(data);
   }

  });
    });


    }); 




});

CODIGO PHP EL CUAL RETORNA LAS EVALUACIONES Y MAS 


     <?php
        session_start();

require"conexion.php";




      $post=$_GET['valo'];

      $usuario =$_SESSION['id'];

      $cali=$_GET['cali'];


$comprobar6 = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM rankin WHERE id_post= '$post' AND usuario_id ='{$_SESSION["id"]}' ");


$count = mysqli_num_rows($comprobar6);



if ($count == 0) {

$insert= mysqli_query($conexion," INSERT INTO rankin(id_post,usuario_id,valor,fecha)VALUES('$post','$usuario','$cali',now())");
$rangoses = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT SUM(valor) AS valor5 FROM rankin WHERE  id_post='$post'");
       $ranger=mysqli_fetch_array($rangoses);
 $valores= $ranger["valor5"];
$insert2= mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE contenido SET rango ='$valores' WHERE id = '$post'");
$update =mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE contenido SET evaluaciones = evaluaciones+1 WHERE id = '$post'");

   $comprobar1 = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM rankin WHERE id_post= '$post' ");

   $valor1= mysqli_num_rows($comprobar1);

 $valor2= $ranger["valor5"];
 echo json_encode(array("valor1" => $valor1, "valor2" => $valor2));
 header("Content-Type: application/json");
}

else{
$rangos = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT SUM(valor) AS valor4 FROM rankin WHERE  id_post='$post'");
       $rangor=mysqli_fetch_array($rangos);
 $valor2= $rangor["valor4"];

  $delete = mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE rankin SET valor ='$cali' WHERE id_post = '$post' AND usuario_id ='{$_SESSION["id"]}' ");
  $update2 =mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE contenido SET rango='$valor2' WHERE id = '$post' ");


 echo json_encode(array("valor2" => $valor2));
 header("Content-Type: application/json");
}


?>
```

Comment: Seguramente estas usando "id" para referenciar a tus publicaciones, prueba cambiarlo a "class" tanto en el HTML como en tu codigo Javascript. id tiene que ser utilizado para referenciar un elemento unico en el DOM si vos queres tener elementos "repetidos" debes utilizar "class"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sólo puedes tener un elemento con id = formulario

```
<!-- ESTE ES EL FORMULARIO PARA EVALUAR LAS PUBLICACIONES 
     EL CUAL SOLO LA PRIMERA PUBLICACION LO TOMA LAS DEMAS NO -->
<form 
   name="val" action="evaluaciones.php" method="GET" id="formulario">
```

y..

```
/* EL PREVENTDEFAULT  SOLO ME FUNCIONA LA ULTIMA PUBLICACION 
   ESTE ES EL ERROR CON EL CUAL NO HE PODIDO DAR   */

$(".calificar").click(function(e){
  $("#formulario").submit(function(e){
```

Mi sugerencia:
Agregamos una clase (que si se puede repetir) a los formularios

```
<!-- ESTE ES EL FORMULARIO PARA EVALUAR LAS PUBLICACIONES 
     EL CUAL SOLO LA PRIMERA PUBLICACION LO TOMA LAS DEMAS NO -->

<form 
   name="val" action="evaluaciones.php" method="GET" 
   class="formularioVotos" id="formulario-<?php echo $registro['id'];?>">
```

y.. mas abajo asignamos el evento a la clase y no al ID

```
/* EL PREVENTDEFAULT SOLO ME FUNCIONA LA ULTIMA PUBLICACION 
   ESTE ES EL ERROR CON EL CUAL NO HE PODIDO DAR   */

$(".calificar").click(function(e){
  $(".formularioVotos").submit(function(e){
```

fíjate que el ID de cada formulario (para que sea único) se arma con el texto "formulario-" mas el id de registro `$registro['id']` asi varía por cada formulario impreso.

Comment: rayos lo estoy intentando me reenvia el formulario de todas maneras el contardor id del formulario si que estoy poco confuso pues, puedes ser un poco mas espesifico ? estaria bien si le agrego un id #formulario mas el id de las publicacines ejemplo: id="formulario<?php$registro['id']?> "

Comment: si puedes usar el id ese ahi te edito el ejemplo

Comment: vale voy a intentar tio muchas gracias ya te cuento si me funciono

Comment: ademas del id le asignamos una class fijate de que el nombre de la clase  sean iguales en el html y el javascript

Comment: hey man! jaja totalmente funcional eres brillante me funciono muy bien pero surgio otro errorsito durante la ejecucion muy bien me funciono y no se reenvia me puedes ayudar a resolver el nuevo error?

Comment: vale! ya lo resolvi gracias de todas maneras tu idea me ayudo muchisimo man eres genial